# Cypress - Can't type in field

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

I have problem with typing in one of my fields in automated test.
I can't get this field but I don't know why.

This is my code:

```js
cy.get('#reasonRecommendationByAgent')
  .type('Zdůvodnění doporučení zprostředkovatele', {force: true})
  .should('have.value', 'Zdůvodnění doporučení zprostředkovatele')
```

And this is the error message:

[image]

Is there anyone who has the same problem?

Comment: could you please attach the DOM source code for that element of input field?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try adding a `click()` before you type:

```js
cy.get('#reasonRecommendationByAgent')
  .click()
  .type('Zdůvodnění doporučení zprostředkovatele', {force: true})
  .should('have.value', 'Zdůvodnění doporučení zprostředkovatele')
```

Answer (score 7):

We had a similar problem and I was able to fix by adding click and focused. I think, HELP DOCS documents also recommending this.

> ```
> cy.get('#reasonRecommendationByAgent').click().focused()
>             .type('Zdůvodnění doporučení zprostředkovatele', {force: true})
>             .should('have.value', 'Zdůvodnění doporučení zprostředkovatele')
> ```

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, it sounds like your code is removing/adding the `#reasonRecommendationByAgent` when it's typed into, which is causing Cypress to lose access to it.

Remove any code that might be causing this DOM element to change as it's being typed into and you shouldn't have a problem.